# Complex React propTypes convert to TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть сложная структура propTypes, которую необходимо переписать на TypeScript. Я только начинаю изучать TypeScript, не могу сообразить как должен выглядеть interface. Прошу помочь.

```js
DataTable.propTypes = {
  defaultColumWidth: PropTypes.number,
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    columns: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string,
      })
    ),
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.objectOf(
        PropTypes.oneOfType([
          PropTypes.boolean,
          PropTypes.shape({
            value: PropTypes.any,
          }),
          PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
              value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
              name: PropTypes.string,
              type: PropTypes.string,
              small: PropTypes.bool,
            })
          ),
        ])
      )
    ),
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type DataTable = {
   a: boolean; // свойство/тип
   b?: number; // опциональное свойство со знаком ?
   c: { d: string }
}
```

Поддерживаемые типы можно [посмотреть тут](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IDataTable {
  defaultColumWidth?: number;
  data?: { 
    columns?: { key: string, name?: string}[];
    data?: {
      [key:string]: boolean | { value: any } | { value: any, name?: string, type?: string, small?: boolean}
      }
    }
  }
```